# TreeMap: NavigableMap<K,V> subMap (), does it creates new map object?

Tags: java, treemap

```
public NavigableMap<K,V> subMap(K fromKey,
                       boolean fromInclusive,
                       K toKey,
                       boolean toInclusive)
```

> Description copied from interface: NavigableMap Returns a view of the portion of this map
>   whose keys range from fromKey to toKey. If fromKey and toKey are
>   equal, the returned map is empty unless fromInclusive and toInclusive
>   are both true. The returned map is backed by this map, so changes in
>   **the returned map are reflected in this map, and vice-versa.** The
>   returned map supports all optional map operations that this map
>   supports.

Does this function create new map object? What is stored in the return object?

Comment: If you think it might not return a new object, where do you think the returned object would come from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this function create new map object?

Yes, however this `Map` object doesn't have a new copy of the nodes in the map which hold the keys and values. If you change the underlying map, it can alter this Map.

Answer (score 1):

yes it creates a new map instance but objects in the new map have references on the objects in the old map.
So, all modification of a object presents in the two maps is visible on the two maps since the objects are the same.

Be aware, even if it's a new instance Map. It's not a classic full featured Map instance. You cannot add a new element, just replace or remove elements in the range of the subMap.

**Edit**

> The returned map will throw an IllegalArgumentException on an attempt to insert a key outside of its range, or to construct a submap either of whose endpoints lie outside its range.

For example in the package static class NavigableSubMap of the JDK 1.6 :

```
public final V put(K key, V value) {
            if (!inRange(key))
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("key out of range");
            return m.put(key, value);
}


public final V remove(Object key) {
        return !inRange(key) ? null : m.remove(key);
}
```

It's a good practice to consider and to use a subMap as a subCollection in general (subList too for example) as a view range limited of the original map.

Comment: New element can be added.

Comment: @ daolincheng
yet but only in the existing range. I updated my answer. You can just replace elements.